# proof $\ln \prod^{m}_{k=2} \frac{k}{k-1}=\sum^{m}_{k=2}\ln \frac{k}{k-1}$

Tags: real-analysis

I am looking for the proof of the following:
\begin{align*}
\ln \prod^{m}_{k=2} \frac{k}{k-1}=\sum^{m}_{k=2}\ln \frac{k}{k-1}
\end{align*}

Comment: Can you use $\log(a\times b)=\log(a)+\log(b)$ ?

Comment: Note a closely related post is [Additional insights when converting sums to products](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/155728/602049).

Answer (score 1):

The logarithm of a product of multiple real numbers is equal to the sum of the logarithms of the individual numbers.

Proof:

$$k_1\cdot k_2....k_n = e^{\ln{k_1}}\cdot e^{\ln{k_2}}......e^{\ln{k_n}}  $$

$$k_1\cdot k_2.....k_n =e^{\ln{k_1}+\ln{k_2}+....\ln{k_n}}$$

Taking $\log$ of both sides

$$\ln{(k_1\cdot k_2......k_n)}=\ln{k_1}+\ln{k_2}+.......\ln{k_n}$$